# Module not found error : While module is installed and listed in the pip list

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I have installed `biopython` and related modules but when I try to load them as

`from BCBio.GFF import GFFExaminer
import pprint
from BCBio import GFF`

It is throwing following error,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-5e2a9411b6ce> in <module>
----> 1 from BCBio.GFF import GFFExaminer
      2 import pprint
      3 from BCBio import GFF
      4 import gzip
      5 import numpy as np

~/software/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/BCBio/GFF/__init__.py in <module>
      1 """Top level of GFF parsing providing shortcuts for useful classes.
      2 """
----> 3 from BCBio.GFF.GFFParser import GFFParser, DiscoGFFParser, GFFExaminer, parse, parse_simple
      4 from BCBio.GFF.GFFOutput import GFF3Writer, write
      5 

~/software/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/BCBio/GFF/GFFParser.py in <module>
     30     collections.defaultdict = _utils.defaultdict
     31 
---> 32 from Bio.Seq import UnknownSeq
     33 from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
     34 from Bio import SeqFeature

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'
```

Python version : Python 3.7.2
pip version : pip 18.1

And When I do 
pip list

I see both `bio` and `biopython` in the list

```
bio                               0.1.0               
biopython                         1.74
bcbio-gff                         0.6.6               
bcrypt                            3.1.6               
binaryornot                       0.4.4               
bio                               0.1.0               
biopython                         1.74                
bleach                            3.0.2               
boto3                             1.9.139             
botocore                          1.12.139
```

Any suggestions or help is much appreciated.

Comment: please add code.

Comment: I have the error message while I try to imoort the module, as I mentioned in my question

Comment: Are you executing this code in an IDE?

Comment: I am executing the code on the juypter notebook, I tried it in python interface on terminal as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Your `pip list` doesn't show [bcbio-gff](https://pypi.org/project/bcbio-gff/) package installed.</strike>

Try:

```
pip install bcbio-gff
```

As a further note, [bio](https://pypi.org/project/bio/) is a profiling package, and probably not what you were looking for.

---

Try creating a new virtualenv:

```
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install biopython bcbio-gff
```

Then try running your script again.

Comment: I have it in my list `bcbio-gff                         0.6.6   `. Now I have updated the list in my question as well. No I am looking for `Bio`.

Comment: I have created the virtual env as you defined, and tried import the module in jupyter notebook opened within the `env` and it still throwing the same error

Comment: Are you sure the environment is selected? Try from the python shell for this environment or [make the venv available to jupyter](https://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/).

Comment: I followed all the steps in the link but still in juypter notebook it is not able to load the module. However, I can import it on the terminal in the new env.Hence, accpeting your answer!

Comment: When you run `which pip` and `which jupyter` what is the output? I think that your pip maybe in a different location to your jupyter installation. These should be in the same `bin` directory for your environment

Comment: `which pip`: `/Users/name/Documents/tasks/venv/bin/pip` and the `which jupyter `:  `/Users/name/Documents/tasks/venv/bin/jupyter`

Comment: Final question, if you `cd /Users/name/Documents/tasks/venv/bin/` and run `ls -la` where does the executable `python3` point to?

Comment: Here is it :
`python3 -> /Users/name/software/anaconda/bin/python3`

Comment: It is probably that your anaconda installation is not correctly placed in your path. I'm not too sure how to fix this, but you could try rebooting (if you've only recently installed anaconda) or making sure that anaconda is the first python on your path.